# Finger sequence – find the continuation

Tags: visual, sequence

Pick the correct continuation for the sequence.

> [image]
>
> Options:
>   [image]

Hint:

> Two of the options are legal symbols in the sequence, two are not.

Comment: I just love visual puzzles even when there's no time solve them.

Comment: are the examples all legal symbols in this sequence?

Comment: @Jasen Not necessarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll go with

> **C**

because I'm squinting hard enough to see

> rotated Roman numerals in a descending sequence.

Like so:

> [image]

This also fits the hint of only two options being legal, since

> ```
>  A = IX 
>  B = IVI (illegal)
>  C = III
>  D = IIII (should be IV, since we are not a clock)
> ```

Comment: This is the intended answer. Nice work!

Answer (score 4):

I think it's

> **C**

Because

> You're counting binary top down, with finger = 1 and space = 0
> So the sequence is:
> 1011 = 11  $->$ 1100 = 12  $->$ 1101 = 13
> Next would be: 1110 = 14 
> Which equates to *'finger-finger-finger-space'* which is picture **C**

Comment: I think that the gaps between the fingers do matter. Also, the second element has a gap too.

Comment: Gaps are covered in my answer, but I see what you mean about the second picture.  There is some space there, though it's smaller than all other gaps.  I immediately read those fingers as 'together' but could definitely be wrong.

Comment: the second sign has a gap,