# A Pixelated Sequence - Find the Continuation

Tags: visual, sequence

A late question inspired by [Finger sequence – find the continuation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86336/finger-sequence-find-the-continuation)

How should the grid above the '10' be coloured?

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We need this (modulo any careless mistakes I've made):

> [image]

Explanation:

> each of our numbers (ONE, TWO, SIX, TEN) happens to have three letters in its English name, and the colours correspond to pixels present when we write those letters in the grids. Blue for the first letter, yellow for the second, red for the third, overlaid "paint-fashion" so e.g. blue + yellow = green. Pixels not present in any letter are left white. (All three colours together are taken to yield brown.)

Answer (score 5):

Just a visual cue of Gareth's answer

> [image]